# How to make loop execute one iteration per 2 seconds with yield?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield, coroutine

Can't understand logic of the coroutine's work. In my example, as I understand, loop must execute one iteration per two seconds, but after start the program it waits for two seconds and execue a whole loop.

Can't understand, what's wrong.

```
    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine ("MyCoroutine");
    }

    IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);      

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(i); // It must execute ont time per 2 seconds?
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to put the yield waitforseconds inside the loop - that's the line where unity interrupts and waits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should yield waiting on each step of a loop:

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(i); // before waiting
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        // after waiting
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand how works **WaitForSeconds**, but I want to know, what for **yield return null;** needs in the loop

Comment: yield return null waits 1 game frame. So if you put yield return null in the loop it will execute once per frame.